# Ford EcoBoost 1,6, loss of fuel performance

Tags: engine, ford, fuel-consumption, performance, grand-c-max

Ford EcoBoost 1,6, 150 hp engine from 2013, mounted in a Ford Grand C-max. Engine failed as a result of a failing ignition coil. Both the ignition coil and spark plug were changed for the specific cylinder. Additionally the fuel pump was changed, as it was listed in the log. Turbo log shows no fault.

However, performance of the car has decreased significantly, maybe 50% on average consumption. The main indicator is during acceleration, when maintaining speed, the performance shows only a slight decrease in performance.

The mechanic says it will be very expensive to find the failure, hence i seek help here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: _Fixing_ the problem might be expensive, but finding the source of the problem should be reasonably straight forward. Of course, not every mechanic/shop is willing to do the detective work necessary to find the actual problem and some may just fire the parts canon at the car, replacing things until something magically fixes it. If this is your mechanics technique, then yeah, "finding" the problem might be costly.

Comment: Hi FreeMan
Apparently it is not as straight forward as two independent mechanics have shown few clues to the origin of the problem. Hence my independent motivation for finding clues. Only clue I have gained so far is fuel nozzles/injectors.